# Missing the ORACLE connection manager type in "Add SSIS Connection Manager" list. (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2019, attunity

I can't see any ORACLE components in my Visual Studio, although I installed software/components/connectors in the order described in Microsoft Documentation.
I can't set up the Oracle connection for the SSIS packages; the "Oracle Source" and "Oracle Destination" are not on the list of SSIS Toolbox.
I can't work on existing projects that contain Oracle connections. It gives me an error message.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I googled that kind of issue and all solutions I found converged to the wrong versions of Microsoft Connector for Oracle and Attunity SSIS Ora Adapters. I reinstalled everything and tried different combinations, but it didn't help.

[image]

[image]

The main question is:
How do I add the OracleConn.dll file in this file path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Connections  To the list of options for SSIS Connection Manager in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Tools" menu and select "Choose Toolbox Items."

In the "Choose Toolbox Items" window, select the ".NET Framework Components" tab.

Click the "Browse..." button.

In the "Add/Remove Toolbox Items" dialog, navigate to the location of the OracleConn.dll file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Connections`.

Select the OracleConn.dll file and click the "Open" button.

The OracleConn.dll file will be added to the list of components in the "Choose Toolbox Items" window. Make sure the checkbox next to it is selected.

Comment: Hi Amira, thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work.
I followed the way you had described, and when I tried to add OracleConn.dll from the specified directory, I got the error message "OracleConn.dll is not valid".
But when I checked the list of components in the "Choose Toolbox Items" window, I found out that 4 ORACLE components already exist in that list:
OracleCommand,
OracleComandBuilder,
OracleConnection,
OracleDataAdapter.
And checkboxes next to them are selected.